# Laravel: Sessions not saving

Tags: php, session, laravel

So I've read through all the Laravel sessions information and all the stackoverflow questions about Laravel sessions but it's just no help.

Im trying to store the username when I'm logging in, and I want it to show the whole time I'm logged in on a page. Now when I login I get to the main page and the username shows, and I go back to login, which redirects me to the main page and the username is not there anymore. The code I'm using:

```
Session::put('username', Input::get('username'));
$value = Session::get('username');
return View::make('main')->with('username',$value);
```

and then in my main.blade.php:

```
@if(!empty($username))
     {{$username}}
@endif
```

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. I'm doing it exactly like all the examples.
What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What do you have in your `app/config/session.php`?

Comment: @Dencker There's alot. What do you need to know?

Comment: Oh, and by the way, the `@if...` can be shortened to `{{ $username or '' }}`

Comment: @Dencker 'driver' => 'file'

Comment: Okay, now - the "files"-key says `storage_path().'/sessions'`, right? If so, fire up a terminal, go to your project root and type `chmod -R a+rwx app/storage`. Maybe it's necessary to put `sudo` in front.

Comment: as @laukasgeiter has already answer the question you can get the user information via Auth and that's pretty easy to go with....!
Auth::user()->yourdbfieldname

Comment: @Dencker yes it does

Comment: @user2736704 That doesn't help if Sessions doesnt work. `Auth` wraps around `Session`.

Comment: So @Loko, try to do the `chmod`.

Comment: @Dencker what do you mean?

Comment: fire up a terminal, go to your project root and type `chmod -R a+rwx app/storage`. Maybe it's necessary to put `sudo` in front.

Comment: @Dencker Im not on linux.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70114/discussion-between-dencker-and-loko).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're not doing it already, you should make use of [Laravels Auth](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/security). Then you don't have to handle the stuff yourself and can just do this to retrieve the username:

```
Auth::user()->username;
```

### Edit

The actual problem here weren't your sessions but the fact that you only passed the `$username` to the view in your one controller and not all the time when your rendered it.

If you want some property of the current user, definitely use `Auth::user()->username`. If you have other session values you can access them directly in the view using:

```
{{ Session::get('foo'); }}
```

---

Another approach are view composers. They let you pass something to the view every time it gets rendered:

```
View::composer('main', function($view){
    $view->with('foo', Session::get('foo'));
});
```

You can put this code in app/filters.php or create a new app/composers.php and include it at the end of app/start/global.php with:

```
require app_path().'/composers.php';
```

Now the variable always available in `main.blade.php` by just:

```
{{ $username }}
```

Comment: So after the: `if(Auth::attempt)`
I can use: `return View::make('main')->with('username',Auth::user()->username);`
?

Comment: @Dencker It's still only showing the username when I logged in and when i go to login and I get redirected back, it forgets the username again.

Comment: You don't need that. You can access Auth::user()->username in your views directly so there's no need to assign it separately.

Comment: @MaGnetas But how about data that I don't use in auth. I can just use it like I use in my question?

Comment: Well you don't need to work with your sessions at all. Auth will take care of it. You can always check if the user is logged in (Auth::check()) or get the username (Auth::user()->username). The problem in your code is that you set a session value and then get it immediately and reuse it. So basically if your input doesn't have the username value you will not be outputting it :) I recommend skipping the session part and working with Auth directly.

Comment: @MaGnetas But how about I'm using a different table that has nothing to do with logging in, and I want to get a value from the query and keep it on the screen as long as I'm logged in?

Comment: @Loko Sessions should work totally fine. (If Auth is working correctly that also means your sessions works) Try some other examples from [the docs](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/session) and see if you can get it working.

Comment: @lukasgeiter but you cant see the problem in my question?

Comment: Then you need to put the "set session" part under some condition so it wouldn't get overwritten every time

Comment: @MaGnetas The put session you mean? Under what condition?

Comment: Yes. You should only store the username to the session when the user logs in, not every time you're trying to display it. Also you can access the Session::get in your view directly - no need to pass it.

Comment: @MaGnetas Aha of course that worked. What is better to use? The answer provided by lukasgeiter or sessions?

Comment: I'd go with Auth. Worked for me in most cases.

Comment: @MaGnetas Thanks alot and this also fixed my issue with the other table query.